# Why is ID not being returned by linqtotwitter

Tags: twitter, linq-to-twitter

I am querying my home statuses. However I am finding that the ID for each tweet is not set.

```
        var auth = new MvcAuthorizer
        {
            CredentialStore = new SessionStateCredentialStore()
            {
                ConsumerKey = TwitterConfig.ConsumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret = TwitterConfig.ConsumerSecret,
                OAuthToken = TwitterConfig.AccessToken,
                OAuthTokenSecret = TwitterConfig.AccessTokenSecret
            }
        };

        var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

        var tweets =
                await (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
                where tweet.Type == StatusType.Home
                select tweet)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Why is the ID for the tweets not populated?

I noticed on the documentation page http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Status%20Entity that it states that the field is populated by the user and not by twitter. I am not sure what this means as the ID is returned by twitter.

My end result is actually going to be to get the oembed feed for each of these statuses, so if there is an easier way to achieve this then let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tweet ID from Twitter will be in the `StatusID` Property of the `Status` Entity. Check that field in your `tweets` var.

I think the intent of the `LinqToTwitter` developer(s) <strike>might have been to allow the consumer (you / your code) to assign your own internal `ID` for the tweets. Can't think of any other reason why they'd have another ID field in the same `Status` Entity, confusing for sure.</strike>
is as follows (see comment on this answer).

> `ID` is an input on some queries and `StatusID` is output. This keeps the
>   return values in Twitter's response from overwriting the callers input
>   parameters.

-- Joe Mayo (LinqToTwitter Developer)

Comment: ID is an input on some queries and StatusID is output. This keeps the return values in Twitter's response from overwriting the callers input parameters.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I updated the answer with your feedback.